# Estimation of the $k$-th derivative zeta function

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta-function, zeta-functions

When I was doing some task in number theory which involves bounds for the Riemann zeta function, I was stuck on the following question:

Let $\zeta$ be the Riemann zeta function and let $\zeta^{(k)}$ be the
$k-$ th derivative  of the Riemann zeta function. There exist real numbers $E_{1k}(a)\leq0$ and $E_{2k}(a)\geq1$ such
that $\zeta^{(k)}(s)-a\neq0$ for $\{s\in C;\ \sigma\leq
E_{1k}(a),\ |t|\geq1\}$ and $\{s\in C;\ \sigma\geq E_{2k}(a)\}$. Let
$E'_{1k}(a)$ be a sufficiently small constant for example
$E'_{1k}(a)\leq min\{E_{1k}(a),-1\}$ such that
$\left|\frac{a}{\zeta^{(k)}(s)}\right|<1$ for $\sigma\leq
E'_{1k}(a)$ and $|t|\geq 1.$

Let  $\delta=-E'_{1k}(a)$ and let $A$ be a positive large real number and $A < D\leq 2A.$

My question is the following:

Can we have an explicit value for $\frac{\zeta^{(k)}(1-s)}{\zeta(s)}$ or 
are there  some estimations for the term  $\frac{\zeta^{(k)}(1-s)}{\zeta(s)}$?
Note: for $1+\delta+iA\leq s \leq 1+\delta+iD.$

Many thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by explicit value or estimations?

Comment: @Peter I mean can we find a formula of the form $$\zeta^{(k)}(1-s)/\zeta(s) = A(s)+O(), $$ with $A(s)$ is the principal term and $O$ is the big Oh.

Comment: For what range of $s$?

Comment: @PeterHumphries I edited the post!

Comment: Same comment as before : where does it come from, what do you want to do ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by $1+\delta+iA\leq s \leq 1+\delta+iD$, as complex numbers don't satisfy inequalities.  Do you mean $s$ on the vertical line segment connecting those two points?

Comment: @Stopple Yes I mean this!